# I need to remove duplicate values SQL Left Join

Tags: mysql

My SQL code:

```
SELECT
users.id,
users.username,
job.category,
locations.location
FROM users
INNER JOIN job ON users.username = job.username
INNER JOIN locations ON job.username = locations.username
```

Results:

```
5   Don   Fashion/Design/Beauty         Mr
5   Don   Eng                           Mr
5   Don   Arts/Audio/Video Technology   Mr
5   Don   Fashion/Design/Beauty         Colombo
5   Don   Eng                           Colombo
5   Don   Arts/Audio/Video Technology   Colombo
5   Don   Fashion/Design/Beauty         gm
5   Don   Eng                           gm
5   Don   Arts/Audio/Video Technology   gm
```

I need to remove those 6 duplicate results in SQL to get the below results. Please kindly help me to figure out this.

```
5   Don   Fashion/Design/Beauty         Mr
5   Don   Eng                           Colombo
5   Don   Arts/Audio/Video Technology   gm
```

Comment: I don't see any duplicates.

Comment: Nor any LEFT join.

Comment: On what criteria do you decide to remove certain data and retain other data? You will have to explain your logic. Is there a missing `PRIMARY KEY`?. You could also provide a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk) with your table and data? p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to display in the format you want (without a lot of extra work and an assumption that there are always as many locations as job categories.)

Using [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) however will allow you to return 1 row per username which contains all the information you seek, regardless of the number of job categories and locations.

```
SELECT
users.id,
users.username,
GROUP_CONCAT(job.category) AS job_categories,
GROUP_CONCAT(locations.location) AS locations
FROM users
INNER JOIN job ON users.username = job.username
INNER JOIN locations ON job.username = locations.username
GROUP BY users.id
```

It will return results like:

```
5   Don   Fashion/Design/Beauty,Eng,Arts/Audio/Video Technology        Mr,Colombo,gm
```

Comment: Don't forget that the default maximum size for GROUP_CONCAT-enated strings is 1024 (Bytes or Characters?). You should up that default if you are going to have large amounts of data! Check out the docco!